# Nomenclature and line breaks

Tags: line-breaking, brackets, nomenclature

I'm trying to format the nomenclature such that there is, ideally, a curly bracket around a series of items with 1 definition.  If that's not possible then at least having a line break in between successive items then having the definition in the middle would be great.

(I've read the documentation and it says that `You can have have line breaks in the argument' but I have been unsuccessful at implementing it).

I've included a relatively short working code showing what I would ideally like in the nomenclature.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\printnomenclature

\begin{equation*}
\left[K\right]=
    \begin{pmatrix}
K_{xx}  &   K_{xy}      \\
K_{yx}  &   K_{yy}      \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\nomenclature{$K$, $K_x$, $K_y$, $K_{xx}$, $K_{yy}$, $K_{xy}$, $K_{yx}$}{Permeability values {$[m^2]$}}%
\end{equation*}

$\left.
    \begin{aligned}
    &K,    \\
    &K_x,~K_y,    \\
    &K_{xx},~K_{yy},    \\
    &K_{xy},~    \&~K_{yx}
    \end{aligned}
\right\}$Permeability values {$[m^2]$}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have a workaround appended.  Essentially adding either `\begin{aligned}` and `\end{aligned}` allows you to add line breaks.  For what I was looking to do I found an rrcases command which makes it look nice.

```
 %Nomenclature curly braces
 \makeatletter
 \newenvironment{rrcases}{%
\matrix@check\rrcases\env@rrcases
 }{%
\endarray\right\rbrace%
 }
 \def\env@rrcases{%
\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
\left.
\def\arraystretch{1.7}%
\array{@{}l@{~}l@{}}%
 }
 \makeatother

\nomenclature{$\begin{rrcases}K\\K_x\\K_y\\K_{xx}\\K_{yy}\\K_{xy}\\K_{yx}\end{rrcases}$}{Permeability values\nomunit{m^2}}%
```